# How is a website hacked by a "maliciously encoded image that contained a PHP script hidden inside it"?

Tags: php, image, openx

My ad server has been hacked over the weekend.

It seems to be a widespread problem, according to [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/185352/hackers_hit_openx_ad_server_in_adobe_attack.html).

There is something in there that got me thinking...

> Attackers used one attack to get login
>   rights to his server, and then
>   uploaded a maliciously encoded image
>   that contained a PHP script hidden
>   inside it, he said. By viewing the
>   image, attackers forced the script to
>   execute on the server

How is this possible? Does it rely on the image being opened with GD or similar? Do they upload a script posing as an image, and somehow include it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It can be as simple as uploading a file like

```
GIF89a<?php
echo 'hi';
```

If your upload script tests the content type via [fileinfo](http://docs.php.net/book.fileinfo) or `mime_content_type()` it is recognized as "GIF image data, version 89a" since `GIF89a` is the only pattern/magic number that is required to identify a file as gif.
And the OpenX upload script apparently kept the proposed filename, i.e. it was possible to save this "image" as foo.php on the server. Now, if you requested that file via `http://hostname/uploaddir/foo.php` the script was executed as a php script because webservers usually/often determine the content type only by the filename extension, e.g. via

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

php then echoes the leading `GIF89a` and executes the `<?php ...code...` block.
Putting the <?php block into a gif comment is slightly more sophisticated but basically the same thing.

Comment: see http://secunia.com/advisories/37475/ : "The vulnerability is caused due to the banner-edit.php script allowing the upload of files with arbitrary extensions to a folder inside the webroot."

Comment: Wow, even the `file` utility in Linux is fooled by this!

Answer (score 5):

Your server is parsing that file for w/e reason. The attackers are putting the PHP into the image comment.

How are you validating the file is an image? If you do it solely on mime type, then I believe they can fake the image header and include whatever they want after that. [VolkerK has a practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597082/how-is-a-website-hacked-by-a-maliciously-encoded-image-that-contained-a-php-scri/3597142#3597142)

In the perfect world, I wouldn't serve *any* public facing images via PHP for fear of such an issue.

Serve the image directly using the server; A good suggestion is to save those images to a directory where they can be served **without** PHP.

I think that's the gist of it, someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How does one add code to an image via the comments? I'm interested in making an image to test some of my other sites.

Comment: So basically, you're saying the same as me, right? The image gets included. How else would the server execute it?

Comment: Any standard image editor will be able to do it. Here's how you add a comment in GIMP: http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/4104/createanewimage001.png

Comment: @The The point is not how you're able to embed the PHP code. It's why is the server executing it.

Comment: see http://secunia.com/advisories/37475/ : "The vulnerability is caused due to the banner-edit.php script allowing the upload of files with arbitrary extensions to a folder inside the webroot."

Comment: It might be even worthwhile to load the image data via imagegif() or similar and then save _that_ file with a fixed filename extension, though it puts considerably more strain on the server.

Answer (score 2):

The only possibility I see for a server compromise is the image being `include`d instead of read through e.g. `readfile` and other stream functions.

Comment: You are right, but maybe I'm missing something, why would anyone `include` an image? Maybe some poor PHP based cache control that instead of `echo readfile($file)` after custom headers it just `include`s.

Comment: @alex I don't know why someone would do that, but I've seen it on SO.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this kind of mistake, too, in production code. That's as bad as it can get.