# What should I use to detect mimetypes reliably?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mime-types

I tried using mimetype-fu to detect mimetypes, but it seems to work for some files, while for others it doesn't. For example, I downloaded [this R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf), and I tried to detect it's mimetype, via:

```
File.mime_type?(File.read("R-intro.pdf"))
```

and it tells me that the mimetype is `"unknown/unknown"`. Is there another way of detecting mimetypes? Is there maybe another mimetype-fu option that I'm not aware of, that could handle this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600679/detect-mime-type-of-uploaded-file-in-ruby

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html#method-c-lookup_by_extension

Comment: As far as I can see, the project hasn't been updated for the past 2 years, I'll give it a try though. I don't want to stick to using extensions to guessing mimetypes.

Comment: @apneadiving, I tried `filemagic`, it did the job. Add an answer, I'll mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, [filemagic](https://github.com/ricardochimal/ruby-filemagic#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8) is a good fit.