# How do you test File content_type in Rails spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, rspec, content-type

I have a conditional that checks for the `content_type` off of a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` but the `File` class in Ruby doesn't have something like that so is it possible to test this rspec?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600679/detect-mime-type-of-uploaded-file-in-ruby

Comment: It would be easier to answer the question if you post this code