# Mime Type file checking only fails when uploading using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use this code to upload files to server and it's working fine.

Now am trying to check mime file types before allowing files upload using  carrierwaves function.

I try using Ruby Filemagic() as suggested in solution found here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600679/detect-mime-type-of-uploaded-file-in-ruby/16635245) but seems to be outdated as it requires Ruby version less than 2.5.0

### My success

I try using Ruby `MIME::Types.type_for()` validation.

It works fine when reading files directly from disk as per code below

```
check=MIME::Types.type_for("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/america.jpg").first.content_type
```

### My issues

If I try reading the files as part of form upload, it will display error

```
undefined method `chomp' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0953a828>
```

as per code below

```
check=MIME::Types.type_for(image_params['attachment']).first.content_type
```

It seems pattern of checking when reading files from disk is different when reading files as part of form uploads. I guess something like mime vs content_type.

Here is **image_controller**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController

   def create


      print(' para: ', image_params['name'])
      print(' para: ', image_params['attachment'])

      #check=MIME::Types.type_for("C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/america.jpg").first.content_type
      check=MIME::Types.type_for(image_params['attachment']).first.content_type
      print(check)

      @imagefile = Imagefile.new(image_params)

      if @image.save
         redirect_to images_path, notice: "file has been uploaded."
      else
         render "new"
      end

   end

   private
      def image_params
      params.require(:image).permit(:name, :attachment)
   end

end
```

**Attachment _controller**

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   storage :file

    def store_dir
       "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
   end

   def extension_white_list
      %w(pdf doc htm html docx png jpg gif)
   end
```

**image model**

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
   mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader # Tells rails to use this uploader for this model.

   validates :name, :attachment, presence: true # Make sure the owner's name is present.

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mimemagic gem  is what works for me

The library to detect the mime type of a file by extension and by content.

[source](https://github.com/minad/mimemagic)

detects mimetypes by using extension name

```
 MimeMagic.by_path('nancy.png')
```

detects mimetype by reading the file content

```
  MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open('nanc.png'))
```