# Trying to detect mime types with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 5.x and cannot figure out how to automatically detect mime types. I saw this post here [Detect MIME type of uploaded file in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600679/detect-mime-type-of-uploaded-file-in-ruby;) however, when I try to use `require 'filemagic`, I get the following error in the console:

```
# irb                                                                                                                                                                                                                        12:25PM/02.20
2.5.1 :001 > require 'filemagic'
Traceback (most recent call last):
       13: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
       12: from (irb):1
       11: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
       10: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
        9: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
        8: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/filemagic-0.4.0.0/lib/filemagic.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        7: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
        6: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
        5: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/filemagic-0.4.0.0/lib/filemagic/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        4: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
        3: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
        2: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/refile-0.6.2/lib/refile/rails.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/refile-0.6.2/lib/refile/rails.rb:6:in `<module:Refile>'
NameError (uninitialized constant Refile::Rails)
2.5.1 :002 >
```

When I tried to manually install ruby-filemagic using `gem install ruby-filemagic` (in case something was screwed up), I get the following error:

```
# gem install ruby-filemagic                                                                                                                                                                                                 12:25PM/02.20
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-filemagic:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/ext/filemagic
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20200220-8004-1i08kxm.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lgnurx... no
checking for magic_open() in -lmagic... no
*** ERROR: missing required library to compile this module
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-magic-dir
        --without-magic-dir
        --with-magic-include
        --without-magic-include=${magic-dir}/include
        --with-magic-lib
        --without-magic-lib=${magic-dir}/lib
        --with-gnurx-dir
        --without-gnurx-dir
        --with-gnurx-include
        --without-gnurx-include=${gnurx-dir}/include
        --with-gnurx-lib
        --without-gnurx-lib=${gnurx-dir}/lib
        --with-gnurxlib
        --without-gnurxlib
        --with-magiclib
        --without-magiclib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/ruby-filemagic-0.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Since this didn't really work out, I went to the next proposed solution which suggested using `MIME::Types.type_for("filename.gif").first.content_type` for Ruby on Rails, but I cannot use this because I get the following error:

```
# rails c                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Running via Spring preloader in process 8106
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.4)
2.5.1 :001 > f = "/path/to/pdf"
 => "/path/to/pdf"
2.5.1 :002 > MIME::Types.type_for(f).first.content_type
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):2
NameError (uninitialized constant MIME)
2.5.1 :003 >
```

To try to fix this error, I saw the suggestion to put `require 'mime/types'` at the top, but I can't use that either:

```
2.5.1 :003 > require 'mime/types'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
LoadError (cannot load such file -- mime/types)
2.5.1 :004 >
```

All I'm trying to do is detect the mimetype so that I can use it with the `slack-ruby-client`, but cannot seem to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being able to use `mimemagic` instead of the other proposed solutions in that document.

```
require 'mimemagic'
MimeMagic.by_magic(File.open("/path/to/pdf")).type
```