# How to check if multiple files' extensions are in_array

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to upload two images in one form using ajax and php. I'm using `FormData` to get the form's information, which works fine. This is the HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="file">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" class="file">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and here's the javascript code:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');

$("form").on("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var formdata = new FormData(form);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'double_image_upload_response.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formdata,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

On the server side in PHP, I'm using this to get the names of the files:

```
$files = $_FILES['file']['name'];
```

and this works fine. So, for example, if I had two files, one named "tree.jpg" and the other named "orange.jpg", I would get the names in that form within an array, which is good.
To get the names out of the array, I use a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($files as $names) {

    echo $names;

}
```

This gives me the values "tree.jpg" and "orange.jpg" outside of the array. 
However, when I try to check if the extensions are valid, I have trouble. Using this php array containing the valid image extensions:

```
$allowed = ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png'];
```

I then add some code to the inside of the `foreach` loop I just showed, resulting in this:

```
foreach($files as $names) {

    if (in_array($names, $allowed)) {
        echo "Valid image extension";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid image extension";
    }

}
```

and it keeps echoing out "Invalid image extension", but I don't know why. 
I already tried using the `explode()` and `end()` functions to get the extension and compare that to the `$allowed` array, without luck. I also tried the `array_search` function, which didn't work, either. Any ideas?

`

Comment: you comparing apples to oranges, file names to mime types

Comment: your `$allowed` array does not contain file extensions, but mime types. They are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by the commenters, your `$allowed` array contains a list of valid `mime-types`, not extensions. You must decide what you want to use to check the validity of the file.

If you decide to go with the pure file extension, then in the loop you must also extract the extension, and compare that to a new list, one that contains expected valid extensions. Something like this:

```
$files = ['orange.jpg', 'apple.jpeg'];
$allowed  = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'];

foreach($files as $names) {
    $pathinfo = pathinfo($names);  /* split path in its components */
    $extension = strtolower($pathinfo['extension']);  /* extract the extension and normalize to lowercase */

    if (in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
        echo "Valid image extension";
    } else {
        echo "Invalid image extension";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the file extension can be modified by the end-user, you can't rely on it in terms of verifying the file type of an uploaded file. You really need to check the actual content type, which you can do with [`mime_content_type`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php). To use that, you need the uploaded file name, which is in `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][]`. You can use something like this:

```
$allowed = ['image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png'];
foreach ($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] as $name) {
    $mime_type = mime_conent_type($name);
    if (!in_array($mime_type, $allowed)) {
        echo "File type is valid";
    }
    else {
        echo "File type is invalid!";
    }
}
```

Comment: @CarsonD no worries. I typically also include a check that I can call `imagecreatefromjpeg` (or other `imagecreatefrom*` routine as appropriate to the mime type) successfully on the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing filenames like "tree.jpg" , "orange.jpg" with mime type 'image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg'. Get the file extension using following function.then compare with required file extension in array.

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$allowed = ['pjpeg', 'jpeg',...]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rely on the client file type which is not secure, you can do it like this,

```
$file_types = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
if (in_array($names, $allowed)) {
    echo "Valid image extension";
} else {
    echo "Invalid image extension";
}
```

But you'd better not do it.

Refer to [PHP File Type Restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57439850/6521116) and [Laravel: Form file uploads failing - incorrect type detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57425890/6521116)