# How to validade in HTML5 to only allow in 'input type="file"' JPG, GIF or PNG?

Tags: regex, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Limit file format when using <input type=“file”>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

I need to use the HTML5 `pattern` attribute to only allow JPG, GIF and PNG files in a `<input type="file">` element.

I currently have this pattern, but it is not working:

```
<input type="file" class="input-file" id="tbinstUploadFile0" name="tbinstUploadFile0" placeholder="Please insert an image file..." pattern="([^\s]+(\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|bmp))$)">
```

This regex pattern is not compatible with HTML5? How can I test for valid HTML5 regex patterns?

Comment: See accept in HTML5 spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#attr-input-accept

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try something like

```
<input type="file" name="my-image" id="image" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" />
```

Click [here for the latest browser compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-accept)

Live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rb1n9bfe/)

To select only image files, you can use this `accept="image/*"`

```
<input type="file" name="my-image" id="image" accept="image/*" />
```

Live demo [here](http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/07-accept.html)

[image: Only gif, jpg and png will be shown, screen grab from Chrome version 44]
Only gif, jpg and png will be shown, screen grab from Chrome version 44

Comment: It is not supported in Firefox 12. Thanks by the reply.

Comment: only works in Chrome as per end 2013.

Comment: If I am adding this(`accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png"`) to `input` tag, it's showing me all file types in Firefox, where as if I just keep `accept="image/*"`, it works. I just want the user to select `jpg, jpeg` and `png` format.

Comment: Custom Files can change to All files then it shows all files such as image,txt file,pdf etc.

I suggest validated it using java script in client site then server site script before processing.

Demo: http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4Q8H9E/

Comment: why its not working for only image/jpg ??

Comment: @santosh Did you try `accept="image/*"` ?

Comment: @kiranvj but i want only .jpg format image to be uploaded......

Comment: @santosh `<input type=file accept="image/jpg">` should work only for jpg.

Comment: Something like this is not secure and someone with enough knowledge to Inspect Element and remove the attribute accept will be able to upload malicious files to your webserver. First do the proper filetype checking on the backend and THEN do it on client side.

Comment: @NurudinImsirovic First on client side (as thats where the usecase starts) then on server. Whatever you do on client side can be bypassed. You dont need console for selecting all files, Just change the custom files to All files in upload file dialogm, that will show all files.Extension and mime type validation has to be done in server side.

Comment: @kiranvj Agree! I did not even notice there is "All files" this already exposes a lot of bad things (on Windows) I don't know about Linux but It's probably bound to the OS anyways.. But yes, extension and mime type validation has to be done in server side. 100% true!

Comment: @kiranvj `<input type=file accept="image/jpg">` this wasnt working thats why i have asked.

Comment: @santosh try image/jpeg