# File input: Compare file type and accept only picture formats (jpg, bmp, etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying ot find a way to use jquery to validate if a a file is in picture format `(jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,etc)`. I have been able to figure out if the input is empty or not with simple `.length` comparison. How would I be able to check the file type and only accept valid picture formats.

**Emtpy or not input:**

```
if ($.trim($('#textInput').val()).length == 0) {
    alert("Should Not Be Empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a file input:

```
var extension = $('#file_input').val().split('.').pop();
if (['bmp', 'gif', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'].indexOf(extension) > -1) {
    console.log('validated');
} else {
    console.log('invalid extension');
}
```

For more extensive file-type filtering, you should ideally use server-side validation.

Comment: The variable extension won't contains the file extension if filename contains dots.

Comment: I was using `split('.')[1]` instead of `split('.').pop()`. Basically, if you had a filename like `my.example.jpg`, extension would've been example. This has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a simple function to extract the extension of the file:

```
function getExtension(file) {
    return file.split('.').pop();
}
```

And then you can check the input value:

```
var file = $.trim($('#textInput').val());
if (['gif','png', ...].indexOf(getExtension(file)) > - 1) {
     ...
}
```

And also check this post, maybe useful:

[How to validade in HTML5 to only allow in 'input type="file"' JPG, GIF or PNG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097272/how-to-validade-in-html5-to-only-allow-in-input-type-file-jpg-gif-or-png?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you should not test for valid file types using javascript. Javascript is client-side only, therefore your script could easily be evaded or the user could simply rename their file with a separate extension and your checkpoint would fail.

Look into [MIME types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) and server-side validation of user-upload files. It's a complicated subject and it's up to you to decide how much time you want to spend on it. Security increases with more thorough checks.

The checks I use are file size, MIME type, and upload location (to make sure no one is trying to upload a script from a remote site). These functions in PHP are [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php), [`fileinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php), [`mime_content_type`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), and [`is_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php). Similar functions exist in other languages.

You could go even further and test the bits of the file to ensure it is not malicious code or a file pretending to be a JPEG by tricking the MIME headers, for example.

Comment: + 1, I agree with you, but a client-side verification can also be done, mainly to avoid unnecessary server calls.

Comment: JavaScript can be server side with Node.js