# HTML file input accept only .zip files (not .exe)

Tags: html, file, google-chrome, firefox

using this for the accept field in my file input:

```
application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed,application/octet-stream
```

Result:

- Internet Explorer: Only shows .zip. Yay.
- FireFox: shows all files, but I can change dropdown to only show .zip. Can I change .zip to be the default view somehow?
- Chrome: shows .zip and .exe. How do I exclude .exe?

I know chrome is technically right, but I'm trying to be user friendly here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`application/octet-stream` is the "catch-all" bucket.    It's the default mime-type if the filename has no extension to help determine it.    It's also the source of your EXE representation in Chrome, I'm guessing.

[Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

You can also try reducing it with the "accept" attribute on the INPUT/File.    That link above also has a link to a JSFiddle page you can play and test with.

Answer (score 51):

try

```html
<!-- (IE 10+, Edge, Chrome, Firefox 42+) -->
<input type="file" accept=".zip,.rar,.7zip" />
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="zip,application/octet-stream,application/zip,application/x-zip,application/x-zip-compressed">
```