# html file input accept .zip file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a file input form, and I want to accept zip file only

```html
<input type="file" accept=".zip">
```

But I can still choose some files in other formats:

[image: like this:]

I'm on macOs 10.13.2, Chrome 69.0.3497.100.

I want to know the reason, and how can I select zip file only?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML file input accept only .zip files (not .exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24832275/html-file-input-accept-only-zip-files-not-exe)