# How to access validity of accept parameter in html input

Tags: html, validation, input

I've got a hidden input file field, and I want to restrict the type of files it accepts. 
When a user uploads a file, I use the `convertFile` function to convert the image into a png, before uploading it to the server. Currently, if the user provides a file that is not of a type in the accept attribute, it still triggers the onChange function.

I was hoping I could still leverage the `accepts` attribute, but have been unable to find a way to check that the input fields value is valid.

My field is

`<input type="file" name="imgFile" onChange="convertFile()"  accept="image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png" />`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Comment: @Pekka웃, this is not a duplicate, I am trying to access the state of the input element to see if the file added was valid. It seems accepts only provides a warning, but does not prevent my imgFile from being submitted or triggering the onChange function. I've updated the question

Comment: As far as I can see, the answers in the duplicate provide all the different ways in which this can be done - the bottom line is there is no waterproof way, you will have to check it on server side anyway. Re onchange, that is a different thing then, but if that's your focus you'd really have to rewrite the question completely, IMO