# Oracle ApEx File Browse file limits

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle ApEx, I have a file browse item that receives a picture file.
Is there a way to make it that only image files(or just the standards like jpg, png, bmp etc.) can be uploaded. And also put a (variable) limit on height and width?

The variable for the length and width would be coming from choice made from a select list.

Any help would be great.

And as always, thanks for helping out and not answering about me being a noob.

Comment: Use Dynamic action for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not restrict users what to select from your file browse item but you can give them a "hint". Edit your File Browse item and in the **HTML Form Element Attributes** add `accept="image/*"`

Comment: It's a bummer, but thanks. At least I can point the users in the right direction.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file/4329103#4329103) you can find an example of javascript function that check the extension of the file uploaded. You can use this function like it is or make a dynamic action based on it.