# Interactive directory input in Shiny app (R)

Tags: r, directory, shiny, shiny-server

I am building a shiny app that requires a user to select a folder on the local machine, which contains the files to be processed by the app.

I am using a solution proposed [here](https://github.com/wleepang/shiny-directory-input). This works fine on a local machine, but does not work if the app is deployed to a shinyapps server. 
The author of this solution confirmed that it was only designed to work with local Shiny apps, since it makes OS shell calls to display a directory dialog.

I am wondering if there is a different solution for directory dialog, which will work on the deployed Shiny apps (I am deploying to shinyapps.io).

Edited: Notice that I cannot use [fileInput](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html) interface for two reasons:

1. The users of the app are not technical people and they do not know which files inside the folder are used by the app.
2. The selected folder may contain other folders within which the needed files reside, such that it is impossible to select all files at once, even if the fileInput interface has the `multiple` option enabled.

The folder/files structure is not something I can change, it is downloaded AS IS from a medical device and therefore the only thing I can expect from the users is to specify the parent folder and the rest should be done inside the R code.

Comment: Are you deploying to shinyapps.io or do you have your own shiny-server?

Comment: Either way the best solution in my opinion is rather than store the directory files locally, move the folders to dropbox, then use the rdrop2 package to call whatever folder the user selects and source the data once files are downloaded into the apps working environment

Comment: Hi Carl. Currently I am deploying to shinyapps.io. I am planning to use dropbox in the backend to store the data that is uploaded. However, the users of my app  should be able to upload their files from their computers directly though the app interface without dropbox.

Comment: Oh..I see, I thought you were sourcing from your directories. Why not just use the shiny fileUpload function?

Comment: fileUpload uploads a single file, but I need to upload all files in the directory specified by the user...

Comment: [shiny file input documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/fileInput.html)

read the docs, set multiple=TRUE. You're a tad vague and with no posted code I really can't give anymore insight i'm afraid.

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear. The minimum code for my question is in the link provided in the original question. From the user experience perspective, uploading multiple files is less elegant and less convenient than selecting a folder (the folder can contain hundreds of files). Thus I was looking for a solution for specifying a folder name rather than a list of files. Frankly, I am surprised that (to the best of my knowledge) this functionality is not available in base R or any of the standard packages.

Comment: It is. If I'm at the command line. .. and the folder with hundreds of files is at "/home/data" then lapply (list.files ("/home/data", full.names=T, recursive =T),function (i)file.copy (from=i,to = basename (i))) moves them all onto the working directory. What you're describing would allow users to upload a folder from their home directory's. ..which is malicious if not filtered for say .exe files. Also, I'm sure they could just hit command+a to select all files no?

Comment: My users are non technical people and the folders contain log data from a medical device. All files are text files. no executables. The app will read the folder and allow a user to visualize the data in the folder. It's very important that the app will be user friendly for non technical users, which explains my "obsession" to specify just the folder name rather than deal with the files, which a user should not deal with (the folder may have other files, which will be ignored by the app)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a working example based on using the "webkitdirectory" attribute. At the moment the attribute is supported by Chrome, Opera and Safari (mobile and desktop) and it should be supported in Firefox 49 to be released in September.
More about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitDirectory). It work with subdirectories also.

It requires using the tags keyword in ui.R. I have tested it by uploading three csv files each contaning three numbers separeted by a coma. Tested locally and on shinyapps.io with Chrome and Opera. This is the code:

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    shinyUI(tagList(fluidPage(theme = "bootstrap.css",
                      includeScript("./www/text.js"),
                      titlePanel("Folder content upload"),

                      fluidRow(
                              column(4,
                                     wellPanel(
                                             tags$div(class="form-group shiny-input-container", 
                                                      tags$div(tags$label("File input")),
                                                      tags$div(tags$label("Choose folder", class="btn btn-primary",
                                                                          tags$input(id = "fileIn", webkitdirectory = TRUE, type = "file", style="display: none;", onchange="pressed()"))),
                                                      tags$label("No folder choosen", id = "noFile"),
                                                      tags$div(id="fileIn_progress", class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress",
                                                               tags$div(class="progress-bar")
                                                      )     
                                             ),
                                             verbatimTextOutput("results")
                                     )
                              ),
                              column(8,
                                     tabsetPanel(
                                             tabPanel("Files table", dataTableOutput("tbl")),
                                             tabPanel("Files list", dataTableOutput("tbl2"))
                                     )
                              )
                      )
    ),
    HTML("<script type='text/javascript' src='getFolders.js'></script>")
    )

    )
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(DT)

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
            df <- reactive({
                    inFiles <- input$fileIn
                    df <- data.frame()
                    if (is.null(inFiles))
                            return(NULL)
                    for (i in seq_along(inFiles$datapath)) {
                            tmp <- read.csv(inFiles$datapath[i], header = FALSE)  
                            df <- rbind(df, tmp)
                    }
                    df

            })
            output$tbl <- DT::renderDataTable(
                    df()
            )
            output$tbl2 <- DT::renderDataTable(
                    input$fileIn
            )
            output$results = renderPrint({
                    input$mydata
            })

    })
```

text.js

```
window.pressed = function(){
        var a = document.getElementById('fileIn');
        if(a.value === "")
        {
            noFile.innerHTML = "No folder choosen";
        }
        else
        {
            noFile.innerHTML = "";
        }
    };
```

getFolders.js

```
     document.getElementById("fileIn").addEventListener("change", function(e) {

            let files = e.target.files;
            var arr = new Array(files.length*2);
            for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

            //console.log(files[i].webkitRelativePath);
            //console.log(files[i].name);
            arr[i] = files[i].webkitRelativePath;
            arr[i+files.length] = files[i].name;


            }

            Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", arr);

    });
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I am running this code AS IS and it only allows to select a single file at a time. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using Chrome or Opera? It does not work in Firefox or IE

Comment: I tested now in Chrome and it works! Earlier I tested only in RStudio without opening in a browser and it only allows to select a single file rather than a folder. Strange... Any idea why it does not work in RStudio?

Comment: By the way, is there a way to change the label on the button? In your example it says "Choose File" and "No files selected" next to the button. In my case, I need to say "Choose Folder"... Thanks!

Comment: I'll take a look later today

Comment: I have modified the code. Take a look, but this removes the "No file choosen" text. I guess that will need some java script. Regarding RStudio Desktop, from what I know it is basically a browser it it depends on which layout engine they are using.

Comment: I have modifed the code, take a look. It handles the "Choose file" also.

Comment: Thank you Valter. However, found another issue... This solution seems to copy the files to a temporary location (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp...) and then reads the files. The problem is that the files are stripped off their original names. It's a problem to me, because I need to identify the files by their name... Is there way to keep the original names of the files?

Comment: You should be able to get the original file name with inFiles$name

Comment: I have modified the code. Take a look at the "Files list" tab. It displays all the info you can get about the uploaded files.

Comment: Valter, one more question... I notice now that this solution uploads all contents of the selected directory. Is there a way to define specific file type (for example .txt) or specific files name pattern?

Comment: Interesting problem. The accept attribute works poorly. I am not sure you have a solution for that, before uploading the files and than filtering on the server. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Comment: I have now another question. I need to upload files from a parent folder that has a few subfolders where the actual files are. A user selects only a parent folder. In this case the suggested solution will upload all the files as required, however I am not able to distinguish from what subfolder each file came. The inFiles$name will only include the base name of the file and the original path information is not available.Is there a way to modify this method such that I can know the original path information on the client side after the files are uploaded?

Comment: I found [this](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/gdd11-modern-web-apps/index.html#15) explanation that uses webkitRelativePath that may be helpful, but don't know to use it in Shiny.

Comment: Hm, maybe a solution based on this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitEntries)? But it is supported only by Chrome. I can take a look at it tomorrow...

Comment: I was able to read relative path by adding 
`for (var i = 0, f; f = e.target.files[i]; ++i) {
                 out.push(f.webkitRelativePath);
            }` to the javasript, but i don't know how to return it to the Shiny input variable or combine it with the dataframe returned in the `fileIn` (that include datapath and name)

Comment: I have managed to get the data into server.R, what do you prefer, should  edit the previous answer or post a new answer?

Comment: I think you can edit the previous answer, because this is very helpful to have the original path of the files. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check the added javascript file and server.R.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks! My only comment is that I was able to add the second javascript to the first javascript file and it also works.

Comment: Where do you put the .js files? Also, where can I find the "bootstrap.css" if it is actually needed.

Comment: You can put the js file in the www folder inside the shiny app folder. Bootstrap is here [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: @ValterBeaković, do you think I could use this implementation in shinydashboard???

Comment: shinydashboard is based on shiny so I would expect that you could use it. This is just my opinion, I haven't used it with shinydashboard.

Comment: Hi Valter - This looks like a great solution exactly what Im looking for!

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried around with the `shinyFiles` package?
There is a widget which lets you chose a directory.
As output you get the path of that directory which you can in turn use to access the files.
Here is an example how it works.

#### server

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # dir
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'dir', roots = c(home = '~'), filetypes = c('', 'txt'))
  dir <- reactive(input$dir)
  output$dir <- renderPrint(dir())

  # path
  path <- reactive({
    home <- normalizePath("~")
    file.path(home, paste(unlist(dir()$path[-1]), collapse = .Platform$file.sep))
  })

  # files
  output$files <- renderPrint(list.files(path()))
})
```

#### ui

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(
    shinyDirButton("dir", "Chose directory", "Upload")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h4("output$dir"),
    verbatimTextOutput("dir"), br(),
    h4("Files in that dir"),
    verbatimTextOutput("files")
  )

)))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This method works great locally, but when I deploy it to the shinyapps server, I don't have access to my local files anymore. The dialog box is empty and does not let me navigate anywhere. I tried to specify a specific directory in roots option (such as roots = c(home='C:'), but it did't have any effect in the deployed app.

Comment: shinyFiles is for server side directory selection, whereas OP clearly want's a client side one