# Read files from local drive and run r code using shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to Shiny! this is what I am aiming at doing:

I need to run my R code using shiny and display the output.
I understand I can use the below code to run an r code

```
source("RCODE.R")
```

But my Rcode requires two files from the user's local drive through shiny.

Is there a way I can let the user select the files and then input them to my R code and then display the output after running the code.

I have followed the

[Interactive directory input in shinny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196743/interactive-directory-input-in-shiny-app-r) for browsing user files

Thank you for the help

Comment: Does your code consists of two parts, namely server and ui?

Comment: Yes it consists of UI AND Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked:

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)

#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Text Mining on R"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Select the Input File',
                accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      fileInput('file2', 'Select the UserTopic file',
                accept=c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv'))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('table'),
      downloadButton('OutputFile', 'Download')
    )
  ))
)
```

**Server.R**

```
#server.R
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  observe({
    file1 = input$file1
    file2 = input$file2
    if (is.null(file1) || is.null(file2)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    data1 = read.csv(file1$datapath,header = TRUE, sep=",",skipNul = TRUE)
    data2 = read.csv(file2$datapath,header = TRUE, sep=",",skipNul = TRUE)
   source("RCode.R", local = TRUE)
    #output$table <- renderDataTable(output2)
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      my_function(file1$datapath,file2$datapath)
    })

    output$OutputFile <- downloadHandler(


      filename = function() {
        paste("OutputFile", " ",Sys.Date(),".csv",sep="")
       },

      content = function(file) {


        write.csv(my_function(file1$datapath,file2$datapath), file, sep = ",",
                    row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
  })

})
```

This code reads two csv files from the Shiny interface and displays the output of the R code, it also has a link to download the output displayed.