# r shiny - upload all files from shinyDirChoose folder to server

Tags: r, shiny

I saved the path of a user-defined folder with `shinyDirChoose`. Now I want to upload files from that user's folder, but I cannot figure out how to do it. 
1) All on the server end?
2) Feeding the file paths to `fileInput` somehow?

This is how I construct the file paths for the three files that should be uploaded.

```
### ui end, to browse to desired folder
ui = fluidPage(shinyDirButton('directory', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder'))

### extracting the folder path
server = function(input, output, session) {
    volumes <- getVolumes()
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
    path1 <- reactive({
       return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
    })

### constructing the 3 file paths
datpat <- renderText({
    req(nchar(path1())>0)
    datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/data.csv")
  })
vispat <- renderText({
    req(nchar(path1())>0)
    vispat <- paste0(path1(),"/visit.csv")
  })
statpat <- renderText({
   req(nchar(path1())>0)
   statpat <- paste0(path1(),"/statvisit.csv")
})
```

So now I have these paths, but how can I use them to upload the related content to the server? A simple `read.csv` unfortunately does not do the trick.

**EDIT - but not there yet...**

Working further with the great help @SBista provided, I think I'm approaching my goal, but see below code...

```
volumes <- getVolumes()
shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
path1 <- reactive({
  return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
})

observe({
  if(!is.null(path1)){
    ### vis1
    vis1 <- reactive({
      datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/visit.csv")
      vis <- read.csv(datpat, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      vis
    })
    ### dataruw1
    dataruw1 <- reactive({
      datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/data.csv")
      dataruw <- read.csv(datpat, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
      dataruw
    })
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, `dataruw1` and `vis1` do not seem to be generated, as I get a 'could not find function' error when trying to use the actual data with `dataruw1()` and `vis1()`. What am I missing? Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try declaring `reactiveValue` at the start of your server function and assign the value when you read it.  The problem with your edited code is that the scope  of your `reactive expression` is limited  inside the `if` condition.

Comment: Has this "upload all files from shinyDirChoose folder to server" addressed?

Comment: @RanonKahn All I can say is that the below answer (or rather what's in the comments with the second answer) fitted my needs...

Comment: I was under the impression that you were trying to move all or selected contents of a folder to a FTP server or the like with authentication etc.

Comment: No, just to upload to the server of shinyapps.io, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy to have found a solution! Big thanks to SBista once more, even though I did it a bit differently. The below code is not just a chunk (as in my original post) but fully functional, provided you browse to a folder that contains a ***data.csv*** file.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(htmltools)


##############################################################################

ui = navbarPage(
  HTML("Title"),
  tabPanel(HTML("<font size=3>Start</font>"),
           sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                        shinyDirButton('directory', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder'),
                        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), selected=';'),
                        radioButtons('quote', 'Quote', c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"), selected='"')),
           mainPanel(
             fluidRow(
               column(6, tags$b(textOutput("text")))),
             tags$hr(),
             fluidRow(
               column(6, dataTableOutput("table"))
             )
           )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  volumes <- getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
  })

  dataruw1 <- eventReactive(input$directory, {
    datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/data.csv")
    dataruw <- read.csv(datpat, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dataruw
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    path1()
  })

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    dataruw1()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

I have modified your app to demonstrate that you can use `read.csv` to upload the file. For demonstration I am reading only one file from the folder and displaying the read data frame in a datatable.

```
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyFiles)

  ### ui end, to browse to desired folder
  ui = fluidPage(shinyDirButton('directory', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder'),
                 tableOutput(outputId = "datpat")
                 )

  ### extracting the folder path
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    volumes <- getVolumes()
    shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
    path1 <- reactive({
      return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
    })

    ### constructing the 3 file paths
    observe({
      if(!is.null(path1)){
        output$datpat <- renderTable({
          req(nchar(path1())>0)
          datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/data.csv")
          dat <- read.csv(datpat)
          dat
        })

      }
    })

  }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Many thanks! This is my first question on SO, so it's great to get such a swift answer. I have edited my OP to show what I made out of your code, but it doesn't work just yet (see edit in post)...

Comment: Solution added as answer. Unfortunately not working on server, only locally.

Comment: `shinyFiles` only works locally. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196743/interactive-directory-input-in-shiny-app-r) link for directory selection while on the server.

Comment: Thanks again! I went with the multiple files option in `fileInput`, which also works fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44464823/r-shiny-get-user-computer-volumes-for-dirgetter-and-shinydirchoose-when-app-on