# r shiny - get user computer volumes for dirGetter and shinyDirChoose when app on server

Tags: r, shiny

While writing the app on my own computer, `getVolumes()` does what I want it to do: starting `shinyDirChoose` off at the root of my computer. This allows to browse to any folder on my computer.

After upload to shinyapps.io, however, I get the server's volumes.

How can I still get the local, user volumes instead of the server's, even when running the app from the server? If not possible, maybe the C: drive?

```
volumes <- getVolumes()
shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
```

Comment: as far as Im aware, you can't. shinyFiles is for viewing the server side filesystem. when running on your machine its considering it the server.

Comment: Thanks @Phi for the reply. So browsing your computer to upload a personal file to the server can not be achieved? That's a shame...

Comment: didn't say you couldnt. said you couldnt using shinyFiles. Take a look at the `fileInput()` function in Shiny

Comment: @Phi: Thanks again. The user files have fixed names (which I can use in the script) but can be in different folders. `fileInput()` requires to select them one by one (or doesn't it?), so I switched to `shinyDirChoose()`. With the file names in the script, selecting the folder is all it takes a user to use the files. I am now wondering about an alternative: can I simple write the full local path in the code (e.g. C)? Or will the app be unable to find it as soon as it is deployed to a server)? Should try...

Comment: And the obvious answer... Error: cannot open the connection

Comment: when I deploy an app to shinyapps.io that uses the `fileInput()` function I can then browse my local machine for the upload file. For multiple files use the switch `multiple = TRUE`. Docs do warn that multiple does not work on older browsers. i'll put the whole code snippet in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works! Many thanks to @Phi.

```
  library(shiny)

  ui = navbarPage(HTML("Title"),
    tabPanel(HTML("<font size=3>Start</font>"),
             sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                          fileInput('files', 'UPLOAD ManderMatcher EXPORT', multiple = TRUE, accept = c('text/csv','text/comma-separated-values','text/tab-separated-values','text/plain','.csv','.tsv')),
                          checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                          radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), selected=';'),
                          radioButtons('quote', 'Quote', c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"), selected='"'),
                          actionButton("Load", "APPLY DATA")
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("StaVst",
                          fluidRow(column(6, dataTableOutput("tabel1"))
                          )),
                 tabPanel("TabFsmSgh",
                          fluidRow(column(6, dataTableOutput("tabel2"))
                          )),
                 tabPanel("TabFsmVst",
                          fluidRow(column(6, dataTableOutput("tabel3"))
                          ))
               )
             )
             )
    )
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    lst1 <- eventReactive(input$files, {
      req(input$Load!=0)
      lst <- list()
      for(i in 1:length(input$files[,1])){
        lst[[i]] <- read.csv(input$files[[i, 'datapath']], header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,
                             stringsAsFactors =FALSE)
      }
      lst 
    })
    output$tabel1 <- renderDataTable({
      req(!is.null(input$files) & input$Load!=0)
      lst1()[[1]]
    })
    output$tabel2 <- renderDataTable({
      req(!is.null(input$files) & input$Load!=0)
      lst1()[[2]]
    })
    output$tabel3 <- renderDataTable({
      req(!is.null(input$files) & input$Load!=0)
      lst1()[[3]]
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 3):

ui :

```
fluidRow(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',multiple = TRUE,
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv'))
    )
```

server :

```
output$contents <- renderTable({
 # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
 # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
 # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
 # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
 # be found.
 inFile <- input$file1

 if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

 read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
})
```

these are directly from the help in Rstudio. I am using a linux machine, but I  don't think that should make a difference.

Comment: I have to admit I overlooked that argument for multiple files. I will give it a go, thanks!

Comment: @JeroenSpeybroeck you should consider accepting Phi's answer and/or upvoting it. Might worth reading the help section of SO as well.

Comment: @Suren Perhaps you should consider suggesting things as a question instead of giving out orders. At the time I issued this question and got Phi's answer, my account was too junior to allow voting & I haven't been around here all that much since.