# Why does shiny app not load local data after selecting directory and file in folder?

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to built a shiny app, which allows the user to

1. select a local directory
2. select a csv from a list of available *.csv files in the folder
3. display the table / work with it.

The app loads a csv, but only for files with a static filename (see datpat static example). I assume the path to the file is the problem. The path to the directory seems to be ok. Also, the app should be accessed online (most likely own server), if this makes a difference.

This is a minimal code, which hopefully helps finding the error. You just have to navigate to a folder, where .csv files are. This example works if you choose a folder with a csv file named "data.csv".
Thanks a lot for your help!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(htmltools)


##############################################################################

ui = navbarPage(
  HTML("Title"),
  tabPanel(HTML("<font size=3>Start</font>"),
           sidebarPanel(width = 2,
                        shinyDirButton('directory', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder'),
                        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), selected=';'),
                        radioButtons('quote', 'Quote', c(None='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"), selected='"'),
                        uiOutput("csv_select"), #button to select files
                        ),
           mainPanel(
             fluidRow(
               column(6, tags$b(textOutput("text")))),
             tags$hr(),
             fluidRow(
               column(6, dataTableOutput("table"))
             )
           )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'directory', roots=volumes, session=session)
  path1 <- reactive({
    return(print(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory)))
  })
  
  ### Select mp4 files within directory
  output$csv_select <- renderUI({
    csvs <- list.files(parseDirPath(volumes, input$directory),pattern=c(".csv"),recursive = F,full.names=T)
    
    selectInput("csv_select","csv-ography",choices=basename(csvs))
  })
  
  
  file1 <-  reactive({
    return(print(input$csv_select))
  })
  
  
  dataruw1 <- eventReactive(input$directory, {
    
    
    #datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/",file1()) # dynamic case, which selects file from folder --> does not work
    datpat <- paste0(path1(),"/","data.csv") # static case, which works after directory selection
    
    
    
    dataruw <- read.csv(datpat, header = input$header, sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    dataruw
  })
  
  output$text <- renderText({
   paste0(path1(),"/",file1())
  
    })
  
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    dataruw1()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server, options = list(launch.browser=TRUE))
```

Comment: Why are you doing `full.names=F`? `paste(single_string)` does nothing, why are you pasting it, and why do you have `file1()` instead of just using `input$vid_select`?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I've set full.names=F as I just need the name of the video for my input selection. You're right about file1() =input$vid_select, but this doesn't change anything.Do you have a suggestion how to fix the problem with data access?

Comment: I don't understand the filesystem layout, and why you would choose to discard the path leading up to the filename. How do you know where to find the file if you don't have the leading path? I don't have `shinyFiles`, does using [`addResourcePath`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/resourcePaths.html) help?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and kept the path of `input$vid_select` but this doesn't make a difference as the path cannot be accessed and shiny just reads the www folder I assume. I tried to integrate your `addResourcePath` suggestion, but failed. Do i have to use it as follows just before the `tag$video` part: `addResourcePath(prefix=input$vid_select, directoryPath=input$directory)`
Sorry, I don't understand syntax of prefix and directoryPath, which is pointed out by the error message: `invalid prefix`

Comment: `addResourcePath` is not for reactive components, including `input$`. I believe it should be added in the top-level of the shiny app, at the same level as `ui` and `server`.

Comment: The path should be updated when I select a new folder. Therefore I need a reactive solution right? Were you able to run the script?

Comment: Tell you what: I know you only want to *see* the filenames, but try this anyway: set `full.names=TRUE`, and change `choices=setNames(vids, basename(vids))`.

Comment: Thanks, but your suggestion does not work. I edited my script from working with videos to loading a .csv file. The problem is not related to loading a video, but with navigating to the right folder.
My update now is based on the example of @Jeroen Speybroeck [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437671/r-shiny-upload-all-files-from-shinydirchoose-folder-to-server)

Comment: Can anyone help?