# Folder selection in Shiny App (locally and on the server) to read the files and save results

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity, shinyapps

I am trying to use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196743/interactive-directory-input-in-shiny-app-r).
The difference is that I want the user to chose two folders, one to save the result of my code, and one that has all files. 
Now the question is that how can I save files in the second folder (input$fileout). Is there a way to pass this path to a function that processes my input files?  I think there will be a permission issue.
Edit: I'd like to use dataHandler inside my.analysis() function as I need to save multiple pngs, csv and some specific formatted files. What would be the best approach? My shinyApp does not print out anything, except that analysis is done, download the result.

Here's the updated ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes) 
library(shinyWidgets)

 shinyUI(tagList(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("lumen"),
                      includeScript("./www/text.js"),
                      titlePanel("Test"),

                      fluidRow(
                        column(4,

                                  tags$div(class="form-group shiny-
           input-container", 

                         tags$div(tags$label("Choose a
    folder", class="btn btn-primary",
                                                              tags$input(id = "fileIn", webkitdirectory = TRUE, type = "file", style="display: none;", onchange="pressed()"))),
                                          tags$label("No folder choosen", id = "noFile"),
                                          tags$div(id="fileIn_progress", class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress",
                                                   tags$div(class="progress-bar")
                                          )     
                                 )),


                                 verbatimTextOutput("tbl")
                        ), 

                       fluidRow(

                         column(8,
                                verbatimTextOutput("results"))

                       )
  ),
   HTML("<script type='text/javascript' src='getFolders.js'>
   </script>")
  )

  )
```

And my server.R

```
   library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(flowCore)
source("myanalysis.R")
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=50*1024^2) 
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
  df <- reactive({
    print(input$fileIn)
    # Below returns NULL, as it does not have any files in it yet.
     print(input$fileout)
    inFiles <- input$fileIn
    if (is.null(inFiles))
      return(NULL)


      my.analysis(fs = tmp,output=input$fileout)

  })
  output$tbl <-renderPrint(
   df()
  )

  output$results = renderPrint({input$mydata
  })

})
})
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

**Option 1**

It you only want to choose a folder in the sever side (that could be the local system if your app is running locally), you can use [ShinyFiles](https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles).

**Option 2**

If your app is running in a server, then is not possible that you can write data to a local directory from your Shiny app. The solution in this case is to save the results in the server and later allow the user to download it using the [downloadHandler](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadHandler.html) function.

Comment: In that case you can use the the option 2.

Comment: Thanks Geovany I found a way. I had multiple plots so didn't know how to use downloadHandler for it.