# interactive load files in client side using shiny app shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a shiny app using shinydashboard that I will deploy on a shinyproxy server but I want the client to be able to browse his own files (**client side**) and load files inside a selected directory.

I am using this post: [Interactive directory input in Shiny app (R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196743/interactive-directory-input-in-shiny-app-r)

HOwever the answer is for shiny not for shinydashboard, this is what I have got so far:

```
header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$head(tags$script(src="./www/text.js")),
  sidebarUserPanel("Panelado variantes",
               subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),
               # Image file should be in www/ subdir
               image = "logoGMX-color.jpg"
               # image =  "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fanfictiondisney/images/9/9e/Pumba_3.j pg/revision/latest?cb=20120708163413"
  ),
  hr(),
  sidebarMenu(
   # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
   id = "tabs",
   menuItem("Archivo variantes", tabName = "filelist", icon = icon("table"),
    tags$div(class="form-group shiny-input-container", 
      tags$div(tags$label("File input")),
      tags$div(tags$label("Choose folder", class="btn btn-primary",
        tags$input(id = "fileIn", webkitdirectory = TRUE, type = "file", style="display: none;", onchange="pressed()"))),
      tags$label("No folder choosen", id = "noFile"),
      tags$div(id="fileIn_progress", class="progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress",
       tags$div(class="progress-bar"))     
      )
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(type="text/css",
      ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
      ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }",
      ".shiny-output-error:after { visibility: hidden; }"),
  tags$head(HTML("<script type='text/javascript' src='getFolders.js'></script>")),


  #ui
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="filelist", "lista de archvivos",
      fluidRow(
        column(12,
          DT::dataTableOutput("tabla_files")))
      )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server = function(input, output) { 
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)
        df <- reactive({
                inFiles <- input$fileIn
                print(inFiles)
                print(inFiles$name)
                df <- data.frame()
                if (is.null(inFiles))
                        return(NULL)
                for (i in seq_along(inFiles$datapath)) {
                        tmp <- read.csv(inFiles$datapath[i], header = FALSE)  
                        df <- rbind(df, tmp)
                }
                df

        })
        output$tabla_files <- DT::renderDataTable(
                input$fileIn
        )

       }

   runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser =T)
```

I am able to open the dialog to browse the files but when the files are uploaded, I cannot see any output on the table

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In this working example, that requires selecting a folder with a `.csv` file in it, I moved the `tabName` to a `menuSubItem`:

```
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "./www/text.js")),
  sidebarUserPanel("Panelado variantes",
    subtitle = a(href = "#", icon("circle", class = "text-success"), "Online"),
    image = "logoGMX-color.jpg"
  ),
  hr(),
  sidebarMenu(
    id = "tabs",
    menuItem("Archivo variantes",
      icon = icon("table"),
      tags$div(
        class = "form-group shiny-input-container",
        tags$div(tags$label("File input")),
        tags$div(tags$label("Choose folder",
          class = "btn btn-primary",
          tags$input(id = "fileIn", webkitdirectory = TRUE, type = "file", style = "display: none;", onchange = "pressed()")
        )),
        tags$label("No folder choosen", id = "noFile"),
        tags$div(
          id = "fileIn_progress", class = "progress progress-striped active shiny-file-input-progress",
          tags$div(class = "progress-bar")
        )
      ),
      menuSubItem("", tabName = "filelist")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "getFolders.js")),
  tags$style(
    type = "text/css",
    ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
    ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }",
    ".shiny-output-error:after { visibility: hidden; }"
  ),

  # ui
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "filelist",
      "lista de archvivos",
      fluidRow(
        column(
          12,
          DT::dataTableOutput("tabla_files")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header, sidebar, body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100 * 1024^2)
  df <- reactive({
    inFiles <- input$fileIn
    print(inFiles)
    print(inFiles$name)
    df <- data.frame()
    if (is.null(inFiles)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    for (i in seq_along(inFiles$datapath)) {
      tmp <- read.csv(inFiles$datapath[i], header = FALSE)
      df <- rbind(df, tmp)
    }
    df
  })
  output$tabla_files <- DT::renderDataTable(
    df()
  )
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```