# input type file, select only .css and font files?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an *`<input type="file" multiple="multiple">`*.
I need to restrict the user to select only css and font files as file types.

Edit : Yes there are plenty question with input type file. But I need specific to only font files and css.
I got it for css but not for font files since there are a lot of different font files.
eg. https://www.file-extensions.org/filetype/extension/name/font-files

Comment: Use accept attribute and Choose you mime types https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Answer (score 0):

You can add accept parameter in input type="file" and write types of extensions you need to required.
For Eg:

```
<input type="file" name="pic" id="pic" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" />
```

Or otherwise you can check extension of uploaded file by javascript after file uploaded by user.

Comment: As explained here though, it's up to the browser to respect this indication or not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file

Answer (score 0):

If you need script validation you can try something like this:

```js
var mimeTypeArray=['text/x-script.csh','application/x-pointplus','text/css','text/plain'];
$("input[type=file]").on("change",function(){
var file = $('input[type=file]').prop('files')[0];
if (file) {
    var mime = file.type;
    console.log(mime);
    var check = $.inArray( mime, mimeTypeArray);
    if (check == -1 ) {// if mime type not found in the array
        alert(' css files only!');
        return;
    }
} 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" multiple="multiple">
```