# fileupload control to show only csv file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Is it possible to allow the fileupload control to show only csv file in asp.net?

When we click the Browse button it should show only csv files.
I used

```
 <asp:FileUpLoad id="FileUpLoad1" runat="server" Height="20px" Width ="400px" accept=".csv"/>
```

But It is not working. Still displaying other files too.

Comment: please check below url [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Comment: that's not duplicated, I used asp:FileUpload!