# Apex File Browse... Mime type restriction text/csv

Tags: mime-types, apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to restrict the files seen by the Apex (5.1) File Browse to only CSV files.  I am scratching my head on this one as when I set the mime type attribute to mime/csv I get all files.  I have tried other mime types `text/*`, `image/*` they work as intended, I only see files these types of files. When I do upload CSV files Oracle sets the mime_type field in apex_application_temp_files to text/csv so this is internally recognised.  I also have the multi-file select option set.

What am I doing wrong?  If this is actually is a bug is there a work around?

Thanks

Bob
Oracle 12c DB, Tomcat, Chrome

Comment: OK, adding accept=".csv" works(see answers) , but why does using the mimetype as above not work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!-- (IE 10+, Edge, Chrome, Firefox 42+) -->
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```

Fill the field "Custom Attributes"[image]

Reference: [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

---

If you need to restrict the upload only for one type of files, so, create a constraint in your table that check if the mimetype is of this type.

[image]

Comment: OK, first off thanks for taking the time and trouble to write this, although at first I was somewhat worried that you had missed the point, CSV and XLSX are not the same, and in this instance I specifically want to exclude XLSX which exist in the same directories as the CSVs they have spawned.  However, using accept=".csv" works, so thanks...  I will not be using a constraint on the table I am populating, don't need it.  A simple WHERE clause on the select taking data from apex_application_temp_files to insert in mine suffices.

Comment: Many thanks, I trusted that you had the necessary knowledge to perform the exchange from .xslx to .csv.

Answer (score 1):

Restriction e.g. to Excel (XLSX)
Under "Setting" set "File Types" with the following content to restrict file browse to XLSX only.
accept=".xls,.xlsx, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel

@See source: https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-accept