# How to restrict the files based on extension using Angular?

Tags: angular

If I  upload .exe or .twbx files then it show the alert message like you could not these type of files using angular 4 in typescript.

Comment: Please can we see your code that does the uploading?

Comment: Bear in mind that the browser is by default an insecure environment (ie. YOU do not have control over it). Therefore even if you restrict what can be uploaded, anyone can hack your code and upload whatever they like. So you still need to ensure that your server-side code only accepts what you want it to.

Comment: its upload exe alse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this.It works for me.

```
var regexp;
var extension = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
if ((extension.toLowerCase() == ".exe") ||
(extension.toLowerCase() == ".twbx"))
{
alert("Could not allow to upload .exe and .twbx files");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code snippet to allow required formats

```
<input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" />
```

Source: [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)