# how to exclude only file types .doc,.docx,.txt and .rtf file types on file dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use the accept of input type="file" with accept to have string as ".doc,.docx,.txt,.rtf" but it still shows .csv.js and .spec.js files

```html
<input type="file"
accept=".doc,.docx,.txt,.rtf"./>
```

Adding a screenshot , this happens to be only on chrome
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Comment: no its not ...i did use accept but i still see non filtered files as well, like js and .spec.js and log files

Comment: even when using SO's snippet as a test you see the wrong files? Hmm, that is odd because I tested in FF, Chrome and IE and still only see the appropriate files.

Comment: It does not show any other files beside `.doc,.docx,.txt,.rtf`. Is it possible for you to add a screenshot if the issue?

Comment: added the screenshot

Comment: Ok so this might be a chrome on Mac  issue. That link I posted mentions trying mime types instead of extensions

Comment: which browser(s) are you seeing the issue in, and what what operating system and version?

Comment: this is on chrome and mac

Comment: again, which versions of Chrome and Mac OS? Does it happen on any other browser on the Mac, e.g. Safari or Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the accept parameter uses the MIME Type, so it may not work .doc
Uses MIME Type for different versions:

```
.doc application/msword .dot application/msword 
.docx application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document 
.dotx application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template 
.docm application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12 
.dotm application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12
```

If you need other types https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types