# How to add extensions filter in ASP net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I was reading several posts on this topic but still can't get it to work.

What I want is for it to be one or multiple uploads, you can "avoid" uploading png, jpg and gif ... and only allow txt or pdf ...
The solution you give me at [Upload files docs.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0#validation)  did not work for me so I turn to you.

I attach my Controller and my Model and the Index.cshtml:

**Model**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PortalDelPaciente.Models
{
    public class FileModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.png|.jpg|.gif)$", ErrorMessage = "Only Image files allowed.")]
        public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PortalDelPaciente.Models;

namespace PortalDelPaciente.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public class ConfigController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SingleFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            string SavePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/assets/plugins/video");
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(SavePath, "archivito.jpg"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                file.CopyTo(fileStream);

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public IActionResult MultipleFiles(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
        {
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                string SavePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/assets/plugins/video");
                 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(SavePath, $"archivito{i++}.jpg"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
model PortalDelPaciente.Controllers.ConfigController

@{
    Layout = null;
}


@*
    To post files to server we need form with post method,
    and additionally browser must use multipart/form-data
    encoding. Otherwise file will not be sent.
*@
<h4>Single File upload</h4>
<form asp-controller="Config" asp-action="SingleFile"
      form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

<h4>Multiple File upload</h4>
<form asp-controller="Config" asp-action="MultipleFiles"
      form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple name="files" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>

@*
    If upload succeeded we will show nice message to user.
*@
@if (ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:20px">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
```

Thanks for all the help!!!

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file ?

Comment: genius!!!!!
I had not tried to make this filter through HTML, but looked at it from the Controller side

thank you!!!