# Allow only specific file type to upload in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor

I am using `BlazorInputFile` package for uploading file in Blazor.

**Problem**

This code does not work.

```
<InputFile OnChange="OnFileUpload" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg" title="Upload jpeg or png image" />
```

How to restrict user to only upload jpeg or png in Blazor? Please let me know if more stuff is required to support the question.

Comment: I am using the latest Blazor as of Feb 2021 and this is working for me, so they must have fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a wrapper to Steve Sanderson's InputFile that has an AllowedExtensions property.
This is an after the fact filter, meaning the user has to upload the file and then you tell them that file extension isn't allowed. There are entire threads on doing the pre upload way, and it is difficult to say the least.

This is the way I did it after the upload:

Nuget: DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload

The full source code including a Blazor sample project is located here:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/BlazorFileUpload

The most relevant part is summarized here:

using DataJuggler.Blazor.FileUpload

```
<FileUpload CustomSuccessMessage="Your file uploaded successfully." 
    OnReset="OnReset" ResetButtonClassName="localbutton" ShowStatus="false"
    PartialGuidLength="10" MaxFileSize=@UploadLimit FilterByExtension="true" 
    ShowCustomButton="true"  ButtonText="Start" OnChange="OnFileUploaded"
    CustomButtonClassName="startbutton" ShowResetButton="false" 
    AppendPartialGuid="true" AllowedExtensions=".jpg;.png;"
    CustomExtensionMessage="Only .jpg and .png files are allowed." 
    InputFileClassName="customfileupload" Visible=false
    FileTooLargeMessage=@FileTooLargeMessage>
</FileUpload>
```

Notice the two properties for AllowedExtensions, and CustomExtensionMessage.

Here is the relevant part of code where I handle the FileUploaded:

```
// Create a new instance of a 'FileInfo' object.
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.Name);

// I don't know if it's even possible for an extension to be upper case
uploadedFileInfo.Extension = fileInfo.Extension.ToLower();

// if FilterByExtension is true and the AllowedExtensions text exists
if ((FilterByExtension) && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AllowedExtensions)))
{
    // verify the extension exists
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileInfo.Extension))
    {
        // If the allowed extensions // fixed issue where uploading 
        abort = !AllowedExtensions.ToLower().Contains(fileInfo.Extension.ToLower());
    }
    else
    {
        // you must have an extension
        abort = true;
    }
}
```

Maybe this will give you some ideas.

If you want to see a live site that uses it, I just published this a couple of days ago:
https://pixeldatabase.net - Edit Images with BQL - Bitmap Query Language

Answer (score 18):

There may have been a bug in the prior version, but to be clear, The **InputFile** component has an **AdditionalAttributes** dictionary that captures **any unspecified attributes**, which then get placed directly onto the input of type file.

```
[Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
public IDictionary<string, object>? AdditionalAttributes { get; set; }
```

This means you can pass attributes that it hasn't attempted to handle, but they'll make it to the right place.

So you can specify an **accept** attribute, or a **class**, just like a regular input tag.

```
<InputFile OnChange="OnFileChange" class="custom-file-input" accept=".csv,.xlsx" />
```

**See also:**

[Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)