# Blazor Server .net 5.0 InputFile

Tags: blazor

I am coding a site that will allow customers to upload files.

My concern is that I don't want to allow the uploading of executable files.

Is there an option to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the accept attribute as per this post:

[Allow only specific file type to upload in blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61432929/allow-only-specific-file-type-to-upload-in-blazor)