# Allowed file types for Spring REST file upload

Tags: java, spring, rest, file-upload, mime-types

I have a Spring REST file upload controller that I need to restrict the allowed file types. I have a predefined list to check against, and I can do it with the following code snippet.

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
        
        if(!file.isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("File name: " + file.getOriginalFilename());
            if(ipConfigService.isFileTypeSupported(file.getOriginalFilename())) {
```

However, as the files being upload could be quite large, I want to reject unsupported files without having to wait for the whole file to be transferred first (which is what's happening in the above example).

Is there a way to annotate the `uploadFile` method to only accept certain types (dynamically pulled from cache/database), or is there a way I can intercept the request to get the name or mime type without waiting for the full binary to upload?

I can see in the request from the UX that mime type is also sent:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarygcPzBq2V6QNzl25V Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="TestFile.mp4" Content-Type: video/mp4


------WebKitFormBoundarygcPzBq2V6QNzl25V--
```

Comment: Have you tried the `consumes` parameter of the `@PostMapping` or the `@RequestMapping` annotations?

Comment: Maybe this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file) be also relevant if you're coding the frontend too.

Comment: @CebrailYilmaz the consumes is actually multipart/form-data, so that doesn't help in this context