# Limiting accepted file extensioins in form does not work

Tags: html, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/edit/post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="add_docs" accept=".pdf, .txt, .doc, .docx, .epub">
  <button type="submit"  role="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

It is intended to accept only mentioned extensions in `accept=".pdf, .txt, .doc, .docx, .epub"` but to my surprise I can upload whatever other exention like `.mp4` in Chrome without any issues.

So I'm wondering what is wrong here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use client side validation with the `accept` attribute.

If you have to make user select any of image files by default, the use accept="image/*"

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" />`

if you want to restrict to specific image types then use accept="image/bmp, image/jpeg, image/png"

`<input type="file" accept="image/bmp, image/jpeg, image/png" />`

if you want to restrict to specific types then use accept=".bmp, .doc, .pdf"

`<input type="file" accept=".bmp, .doc, .pdf" />`

You cannot restrict user to change file filer to all files, so always validate file type in script and server.

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Try this client side javascript validation: for onchange event:

```js
var file = document.getElementById('file_upload');

file.onchange = function(e) {
  var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
  switch (ext) {
    case 'pdf':
    case 'txt':
    case 'doc':
    case 'docx':
    case 'epub':
      alert('Allowed');
      break;
    default:
      alert('Not allowed');
      this.value = '';
  }
};
```

```html
   <form method="post" action="/edit/post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="add_docs" accept=".pdf, .txt, .doc, .docx, .epub">
        <button type="submit"  role="submit">Save</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: I did try both syntaxes `accept=".jpg, .png"` as well as `accept="image/*"` but none worked as it should.

Comment: @Babr Are you doing any server side validations?

Comment: No I don't. I suppose this `accept=".."` should work on the browser.

Comment: I would suggest to do server side validation as well as different browsers behave differently.

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Or you can use javascript validation on client side for onchange event