# HTML file input accept .zip files also includes .xlsx, pptx, .docx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, input

How to restrict input file from accepting .pptx, .docx, .xlsx when using

```
  <input type="file" title="" onChange={handleUpload} accept=".zip" />
```

I want my input to only access .zip no other file type. But when I use the same in accept attribute it also allows .pptx, .docx, .xlsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit file format when using <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0):

you would better use mimetype instead of extension

```html
 <input type="file" title="" onChange={handleUpload} accept="application/zip" />
```

Comment: Even on doing that it takes up .docx, .pptx, xlsx file extensions.