# Perl upload dies when the file is compressed

Tags: apache, perl, upload, mime-types

I have a form designed for uploading multiple text files and therefore I have set the mime type in the HTML form to

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

I am using the following script

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -wT

use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :encoding(UTF-8));
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

my $cgi = CGI->new();
```

However, there is a chance that people will upload a gzip file. I would like to protect against it, but when I upload a gzip file the script crashes as soon as the new CGI object is made with this error message in httpd error_log.

```
...
test.cgi: utf8 "\\xA3" does not map to Unicode at (eval 16) line 5.
test.cgi: utf8 "\\xB5" does not map to Unicode at (eval 16) line 5.
test.cgi: Malformed multipart POST
```

How am I meant to enable uploading multiple plain text files and **not** die when someone uploads a gzip file?

Comment: An interesting read, although not helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328947/limit-file-format-when-using-input-type-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:std` affects STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR, and STDIN is used to receive information from the web server.

Either remove the encoding layer after adding it

```perl
use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );
BEGIN { binmode( STDIN ); }
```

or avoid adding it in the first place.

```perl
use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) );
BEGIN {
   binmode( STDIN );
   binmode( STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)' );
   binmode( STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)' );
}
```

Comment: I tried both BEGIN statements and it still failed in the same way. I also removed the `use open` line and again it failed.

Comment: Thank you ikegami. This is the answer. I had a die statement and then a whole load of `use lib` statements after the posted code and stupidly assumed that that code wouldn't be run. Obviously it is and all those includes also had the `use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );` statement. putting the `BEGIN` statement after the `use lib` statements fixed things.

Comment: `use open qw( :std :encoding(UTF-8) );` only makes sense in scripts. You should not have that in any module. Use `use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) );` in modules if the goal is to affect `open` calls in the module.